# Selenium HTML attribute name to assist identifying content

Tags: html, selenium, automated-tests, integration-testing

I need to verify using Selenium (or similar framework) that certain HTML content/items are on the page using known unique identifiers.

I have control over the generation of the HTML, so I will mark the HTML tags with an attribute, but sometimes the usual candidates of `id`, `name` etc aren't available for me to use.

**Is there an industry standard for such an attribute?**
**If not, anyone have any good suggestions?**

The attribute shouldn't collide with any known attributes of any HTML elements or affect the web experience/behaviour (I don't care if someone reads the HTML source and sees it).

Some ideas I have are:

- trace
- debug
- uid

Here's how I would like to use it for the example identifier "123456789":

```
<a trace="123456789" href="http://www.someurl.com">Click me!</a>
<span debug="123456789">Hello world</span>
<strong uid="123456789">Wow</strong>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a HTML5 `data-*` attribute.

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to
>   the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate
>   attributes or elements.

More information here: [http://developers.whatwg.org/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes](http://developers.whatwg.org/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes)

They won't cause any problems in older browsers: http://caniuse.com/dataset

Comment: Thanks man.  Just did that.  Hopefully they will accept my app now.

Comment: That is *exactly* what I was hoping to find out. Thanks (+1)